# Codeigniter View to PDF

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, pdf

I have used DOMpdf, mpdf, tcpdf and is not succeeded with the output.

I am putting here everything I have tried, including HTML.

***OUTPUT PREVIEW :***

Direct View File: http://jsfiddle.net/QdhdW/

DOMpdf and mPDF Output: https://www.box.com/s/f7cb2283d196db530702

***ISSUES*** :

*DOM pdf :*

- Bad looking CSS (and not exact as per required)
- leaves 6-7 page
- brakes in pdf  the records are out of page then doesn't come to next page

*mPDF :*

- makes output as small as possible, so that all records are covered in one page. (doesn't good as it is for A4 Page)
- The Borders between each rows. (in HTML there is no borders between the rows.)

> I don't mind using any pdf generator library and even if we change CSS
>   or make CSS inline, doesn't matter. The thing is I am seeking the PDF
>   output same as displayed in view File.
>
> Please Help me, to figure it out. Struggling since yesterday.

Comment: do you have a dedicated server? i.e. it's not on some shared hosting or anything? If so I have an answer :)

Comment: This is not even working on localhost ,
i want to make work it perfectly on my localhost and then I will upload it to server.
and I am having dedicated server.

Comment: Can anyone confirm me with the HTML + CSS is ok or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it Solved.

Thanx to everyone for trying.

Solved it in DOM Pdf only, via changing the CSS.

*Edited:*
Make it worked through this

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=507

If anyone else is having issue.

Comment: I was going to comment your CSS. You could have done the entire document in a table, thus making it easier to render correctly.

Comment: @OptimusCrime
You are just late. I did it the same way. Made One Table, instead of different tables. To make it Render.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) it's a shell utility to convert html to pdf using the webkit rendering engine, and qt.

This will give you a much better result than the others as it's not trying to parse the html/css in php.

Comment: Ya git... that was going to be my proposal :)

Comment: I am not able to find the way to use this in PHP !! 
:(

Any suggesting tutorial or documentation !?

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS uses the webkit renderer and can output to PDF.

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart

Answer (score 0):

[pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/) is a web service for converting HTML to PDF.